# Trivialisation of Mobius Line Bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

As I understand it, an open cover of a Base Space and associated holomorphic transition functions on the intersection are sufficient data to define (up to isomorphism perhaps) a holomorphic (complex) line bundle.
So if we cover S1 with open sets U and V which intersect in open sets P and Q such that P and Q have empty intersection (you will note I am avoiding Latex here. Basically we cover S1 with a pair of horseshoes). We define the UV- transition function to be +1 on P and -1 on Q (locally constant thus holomorphic) we have the set up for an (infinite) Mobius band.
What I am strugling to define are the corresponding trivialisations from U or V to UxC or VxC
that correspond to this transition function.
Even Grifiths & Harris has some "hand waving" about identifying points which does not help. I just want to see the explicit map on the fibres over U and V.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Noel R

Comment: A quick suggestion: work backwards. Construct the bundle using the
trivialization, and convince yourself its a Mobius strip.
(By the way, the bundle isn't holomorphic, and this isn't algebraic geometry, it's really basic topology.)

Comment: @Donu: well, it's *real* algebraic geometry (and, yes, basic topology).  

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response to the dual of the question asked (which I now understand from the response below was not even well formed).

Btw I was seeking to understand this on my way to a proper appreciation of the Picard Group (or is that not now algebraic geometry either?)


Comment: The boundaries between alg. geom and topology are pretty fluid,
and I didn't mean to suggest otherwise. But as Scott suggested below,
G & H is not the best place to first learn this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be some confusion in the question: The circle $S^1$ is not a complex manifold, so it does not admit a meaningful notion of holomorphic line bundle.  If you try to construct a complex line bundle on the circle, you will find that it is automatically a trivial line bundle.  If you want to construct a Möbius band as a line bundle, you should take a real line bundle, with the transition functions you specified.

I would recommend a more topological text than Griffiths and Harris for information about the construction you are trying to do.  Perhaps Hatcher's book on vector bundles and K-Theory will help.  It is available on his web page.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my silly mistake so promptly. (Wood for the trees and all that) and for the references. Back to Picard!